# Why is my alert only working in IE not triggered in chrome?

Tags: jquery, alert

I am using some scroll depth solution. It is working in IE, but not in Chrome. I have debug the script and found the location which is not working. See my alert inside the script below:

Why is the alert firing OK in IE 10 and not in chrome 43.0.2357.124 m?

```
/*!
 * @preserve
 * jquery.scrolldepth.js | v0.7.2
 * Copyright (c) 2015 Rob Flaherty (@robflaherty)
 * Licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 */
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    "use strict";

    var defaults = {
        minHeight: 0,
        elements: [],
        percentage: true,
        userTiming: true,
        pixelDepth: true,
        nonInteraction: true
    };

    var $window = $(window),
      cache = [],
      lastPixelDepth = 0,
      universalGA,
      classicGA,
      standardEventHandler;

    /*
     * Plugin
     */

    $.scrollDepth = function (options) {

        var startTime = +new Date;

        options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        // Return early if document height is too small
        if ($(document).height() < options.minHeight) {
            return;
        }

        /*
         * Determine which version of GA is being used
         * "ga", "_gaq", and "dataLayer" are the possible globals
         */

        if (typeof ga === "function") {
            universalGA = true;
        }

        if (typeof _gaq !== "undefined" && typeof _gaq.push === "function") {
            classicGA = true;
        }

        if (typeof options.eventHandler === "function") {
            standardEventHandler = options.eventHandler;
        } else if (typeof dataLayer !== "undefined" && typeof dataLayer.push === "function") {

            standardEventHandler = function (data) {
                dataLayer.push(data);
            }

        }

        if (options.percentage) {
            // Establish baseline (0% scroll)
            sendBaseline('Percentage');
        } else if (options.elements) {
            sendBaseline('Elements');
        }

        /*
         * Functions
         */

        /*
         * Putting this in a separate function because the Baseline event may soon be removed entirely
         */
        function sendBaseline(action, label) {

            if (standardEventHandler) {

                standardEventHandler({ 'event': 'ScrollDistance', 'eventCategory': 'Scroll Depth', 'eventAction': action, 'eventLabel': 'Baseline', 'eventValue': 1, 'eventNonInteraction': true });

            } else {

                if (universalGA) {

                    ga('send', 'event', 'Scroll Depth', action, 'Baseline', 1, { 'nonInteraction': true });

                }

                if (classicGA) {

                    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Scroll Depth', action, 'Baseline', 1, true]);

                }

            }

        }

        function sendEvent(action, label, scrollDistance, timing) {

            if (standardEventHandler) {

                standardEventHandler({ 'event': 'ScrollDistance', 'eventCategory': 'Scroll Depth', 'eventAction': action, 'eventLabel': label, 'eventValue': 1, 'eventNonInteraction': options.nonInteraction });

                if (options.pixelDepth && arguments.length > 2 && scrollDistance > lastPixelDepth) {
                    lastPixelDepth = scrollDistance;
                    standardEventHandler({ 'event': 'ScrollDistance', 'eventCategory': 'Scroll Depth', 'eventAction': 'Pixel Depth', 'eventLabel': rounded(scrollDistance), 'eventValue': 1, 'eventNonInteraction': options.nonInteraction });
                }

                if (options.userTiming && arguments.length > 3) {
                    standardEventHandler({ 'event': 'ScrollTiming', 'eventCategory': 'Scroll Depth', 'eventAction': action, 'eventLabel': label, 'eventTiming': timing });
                }

            } else {

                if (universalGA) {

                    ga('send', 'event', 'Scroll Depth', action, label, 1, { 'nonInteraction': options.nonInteraction });

                    if (options.pixelDepth && arguments.length > 2 && scrollDistance > lastPixelDepth) {
                        lastPixelDepth = scrollDistance;
                        ga('send', 'event', 'Scroll Depth', 'Pixel Depth', rounded(scrollDistance), 1, { 'nonInteraction': options.nonInteraction });
                    }

                    if (options.userTiming && arguments.length > 3) {
                        ga('send', 'timing', 'Scroll Depth', action, timing, label);
                    }

                }

                if (classicGA) {

                    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Scroll Depth', action, label, 1, options.nonInteraction]);

                    if (options.pixelDepth && arguments.length > 2 && scrollDistance > lastPixelDepth) {
                        lastPixelDepth = scrollDistance;
                        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Scroll Depth', 'Pixel Depth', rounded(scrollDistance), 1, options.nonInteraction]);
                    }

                    if (options.userTiming && arguments.length > 3) {
                        _gaq.push(['_trackTiming', 'Scroll Depth', action, timing, label, 100]);
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        function calculateMarks(docHeight) {
            return {
                '25%': parseInt(docHeight * 0.25, 10),
                '50%': parseInt(docHeight * 0.50, 10),
                '75%': parseInt(docHeight * 0.75, 10),
                // 1px cushion to trigger 100% event in iOS
                '100%': docHeight - 5
            };
        }

        function checkMarks(marks, scrollDistance, timing) {
            // Check each active mark
            $.each(marks, function (key, val) {
                if ($.inArray(key, cache) === -1 && scrollDistance >= val) {
                    sendEvent('Percentage', key, scrollDistance, timing);
                    cache.push(key);
                }
            });
        }

        function checkElements(elements, scrollDistance, timing) {
            $.each(elements, function (index, elem) {
                if ($.inArray(elem, cache) === -1 && $(elem).length) {
                    if (scrollDistance >= $(elem).offset().top) {
                        sendEvent('Elements', elem, scrollDistance, timing);
                        cache.push(elem);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function rounded(scrollDistance) {
            // Returns String
            return (Math.floor(scrollDistance / 250) * 250).toString();
        }

        /*
         * Throttle function borrowed from:
         * Underscore.js 1.5.2
         * http://underscorejs.org
         * (c) 2009-2013 Jeremy Ashkenas, DocumentCloud and Investigative Reporters & Editors
         * Underscore may be freely distributed under the MIT license.
         */

        function throttle(func, wait) {
            var context, args, result;
            var timeout = null;
            var previous = 0;
            var later = function () {
                previous = new Date;
                timeout = null;
                result = func.apply(context, args);
            };
            return function () {
                alert("this function is only firing in IE and not in crhome");
                var now = new Date;
                if (!previous) previous = now;
                var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
                context = this;
                args = arguments;
                if (remaining <= 0) {
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    timeout = null;
                    previous = now;
                    result = func.apply(context, args);
                } else if (!timeout) {
                    timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
                }
                return result;
            };
        }

        /*
         * Scroll Event
         */

        $window.on('scroll.scrollDepth', throttle(function() {
            /*
             * We calculate document and window height on each scroll event to
             * account for dynamic DOM changes.
             */
            var docHeight = $(document).height(),
              winHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $window.height(),
              scrollDistance = $window.scrollTop() + winHeight,

              // Recalculate percentage marks
              marks = calculateMarks(docHeight),

              // Timing
              timing = +new Date - startTime;

            // If all marks already hit, unbind scroll event
            if (cache.length >= 4 + options.elements.length) {
                $window.off('scroll.scrollDepth');
                return;
            }

            // Check specified DOM elements
            if (options.elements) {
                checkElements(options.elements, scrollDistance, timing);
            }

            // Check standard marks
            if (options.percentage) {
                checkMarks(marks, scrollDistance, timing);
            }
        }, 500));

    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

I am using this jquery version: jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Comment: *"I have debug the script and found the location which is not working."* - So is there an error message in Chrome's console, or...?

Comment: I used the chrome debuger.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors in your code. I have changed them. They were like:

1. Missing semicolons.
2. Improper initialization of constructor.

**Script**

```
/*!
 * @preserve
 * jquery.scrolldepth.js | v0.7.2
 * Copyright (c) 2015 Rob Flaherty (@robflaherty)
 * Licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 */
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  var defaults = {
    minHeight: 0,
    elements: [],
    percentage: true,
    userTiming: true,
    pixelDepth: true,
    nonInteraction: true
  };
  var $window = $(window),
      cache = [],
      lastPixelDepth = 0,
      universalGA,
      classicGA,
      standardEventHandler;
  /*
   * Plugin
   */
  $.scrollDepth = function (options) {
    var startTime = +new Date();
    options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    // Return early if document height is too small
    if ($(document).height() < options.minHeight) {
      return;
    }
    /*
     * Determine which version of GA is being used
     * "ga", "_gaq", and "dataLayer" are the possible globals
     */
    if (typeof ga === "function") {
      universalGA = true;
    }
    if (typeof _gaq !== "undefined" && typeof _gaq.push === "function") {
      classicGA = true;
    }
    if (typeof options.eventHandler === "function") {
      standardEventHandler = options.eventHandler;
    } else if (typeof dataLayer !== "undefined" && typeof dataLayer.push === "function") {
      standardEventHandler = function (data) {
        dataLayer.push(data);
      };
    }
    if (options.percentage) {
      // Establish baseline (0% scroll)
      sendBaseline('Percentage');
    } else if (options.elements) {
      sendBaseline('Elements');
    }
    /*
     * Functions
     */
    /*
     * Putting this in a separate function because the Baseline event may soon be removed entirely
     */
    function sendBaseline(action, label) {
      if (standardEventHandler) {
        standardEventHandler({ 'event': 'ScrollDistance', 'eventCategory': 'Scroll Depth', 'eventAction': action, 'eventLabel': 'Baseline', 'eventValue': 1, 'eventNonInteraction': true });
      } else {
        if (universalGA) {
          ga('send', 'event', 'Scroll Depth', action, 'Baseline', 1, { 'nonInteraction': true });
        }
        if (classicGA) {
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Scroll Depth', action, 'Baseline', 1, true]);
        }
      }
    }
    function sendEvent(action, label, scrollDistance, timing) {
      if (standardEventHandler) {
        standardEventHandler({ 'event': 'ScrollDistance', 'eventCategory': 'Scroll Depth', 'eventAction': action, 'eventLabel': label, 'eventValue': 1, 'eventNonInteraction': options.nonInteraction });
        if (options.pixelDepth && arguments.length > 2 && scrollDistance > lastPixelDepth) {
          lastPixelDepth = scrollDistance;
          standardEventHandler({ 'event': 'ScrollDistance', 'eventCategory': 'Scroll Depth', 'eventAction': 'Pixel Depth', 'eventLabel': rounded(scrollDistance), 'eventValue': 1, 'eventNonInteraction': options.nonInteraction });
        }
        if (options.userTiming && arguments.length > 3) {
          standardEventHandler({ 'event': 'ScrollTiming', 'eventCategory': 'Scroll Depth', 'eventAction': action, 'eventLabel': label, 'eventTiming': timing });
        }
      } else {
        if (universalGA) {
          ga('send', 'event', 'Scroll Depth', action, label, 1, { 'nonInteraction': options.nonInteraction });
          if (options.pixelDepth && arguments.length > 2 && scrollDistance > lastPixelDepth) {
            lastPixelDepth = scrollDistance;
            ga('send', 'event', 'Scroll Depth', 'Pixel Depth', rounded(scrollDistance), 1, { 'nonInteraction': options.nonInteraction });
          }
          if (options.userTiming && arguments.length > 3) {
            ga('send', 'timing', 'Scroll Depth', action, timing, label);
          }
        }
        if (classicGA) {
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Scroll Depth', action, label, 1, options.nonInteraction]);
          if (options.pixelDepth && arguments.length > 2 && scrollDistance > lastPixelDepth) {
            lastPixelDepth = scrollDistance;
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Scroll Depth', 'Pixel Depth', rounded(scrollDistance), 1, options.nonInteraction]);
          }
          if (options.userTiming && arguments.length > 3) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackTiming', 'Scroll Depth', action, timing, label, 100]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    function calculateMarks(docHeight) {
      return {
        '25%': parseInt(docHeight * 0.25, 10),
        '50%': parseInt(docHeight * 0.50, 10),
        '75%': parseInt(docHeight * 0.75, 10),
        // 1px cushion to trigger 100% event in iOS
        '100%': docHeight - 5
      };
    }
    function checkMarks(marks, scrollDistance, timing) {
      // Check each active mark
      $.each(marks, function (key, val) {
        if ($.inArray(key, cache) === -1 && scrollDistance >= val) {
          sendEvent('Percentage', key, scrollDistance, timing);
          cache.push(key);
        }
      });
    }
    function checkElements(elements, scrollDistance, timing) {
      $.each(elements, function (index, elem) {
        if ($.inArray(elem, cache) === -1 && $(elem).length) {
          if (scrollDistance >= $(elem).offset().top) {
            sendEvent('Elements', elem, scrollDistance, timing);
            cache.push(elem);
          }
        }
      });
    }
    function rounded(scrollDistance) {
      // Returns String
      return (Math.floor(scrollDistance / 250) * 250).toString();
    }
    /*
     * Throttle function borrowed from:
     * Underscore.js 1.5.2
     * http://underscorejs.org
     * (c) 2009-2013 Jeremy Ashkenas, DocumentCloud and Investigative Reporters & Editors
     * Underscore may be freely distributed under the MIT license.
     */
    function throttle(func, wait) {
      var context, args, result;
      var timeout = null;
      var previous = 0;
      var later = function () {
        previous = new Date();
        timeout = null;
        result = func.apply(context, args);
      };
      return function () {
        alert("this function is only firing in IE and not in crhome");
        var now = new Date();
        if (!previous) previous = now;
        var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
        context = this;
        args = arguments;
        if (remaining <= 0) {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = null;
          previous = now;
          result = func.apply(context, args);
        } else if (!timeout) {
          timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
        }
        return result;
      };
    }
    /*
     * Scroll Event
     */
    $window.on('scroll.scrollDepth', throttle(function() {
      /*
       * We calculate document and window height on each scroll event to
       * account for dynamic DOM changes.
       */
      var docHeight = $(document).height(),
          winHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $window.height(),
          scrollDistance = $window.scrollTop() + winHeight,
          // Recalculate percentage marks
          marks = calculateMarks(docHeight),
          // Timing
          timing = +new Date() - startTime;
      // If all marks already hit, unbind scroll event
      if (cache.length >= 4 + options.elements.length) {
        $window.off('scroll.scrollDepth');
        return;
      }
      // Check specified DOM elements
      if (options.elements) {
        checkElements(options.elements, scrollDistance, timing);
      }
      // Check standard marks
      if (options.percentage) {
        checkMarks(marks, scrollDistance, timing);
      }
    }, 500));
  };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: thank you, I copied your script, but the alert is still not firing in chrome. I cleared already the cache.

Comment: It works for me. I didn't try the exact same version!

Comment: maybe it is some combination of many javascripts and jQuery scripts. What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: You need to provide a live example of it!